# Why do people downvote but refrain from commenting the reason?

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

I am a beginner to this stack exchange and I am holding account in 21 sites of stack exchange. I ask a question, I get positive comments and a valid answer . With that am offered with down-votes too which reduces my reputation. When a person gets a valid answer, shouldn't the down-votes go meaningless? Why those people who down-vote do not leave comments explaining why they down-voted for questions which has an appropriate answer ?

Comment: Whenever you are in doubt as to why your post was voted on in a particular way, and the voter did not leave a comment explaining their reasoning further, the hover texts for the vote buttons can serve as guidance. In the case of a downvote, that canonical reason is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Respected @MichaelKjörling . Understand my question clearly. If the question is unclear , then there shouldn't be a valid answer for it. My question is, when a question is answered correctly by another person then it is crystal clear that the question posted is "CLEAR"  which contradicts with the hover text of a downvote.

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran thanks for bringing your question to meta.  I don't know if it applies to the cases you're thinking of, but lots of times I've seen an unclear question garner a variety of answers where people guessed about what was meant -- and guessed differently, so when the question was later clarified some of those answers didn't work so well any more.  In that case I would vote to put on hold as unclear (to prevent more of that); I know your question is about downvotes, not close votes, but I just wanted to point out a case where having answers doesn't mean it was clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As one of the people who *sometimes* downvote without any comments, I will try to list for you **my personal reasons for downvoting**:

**1: You are too political, borderline trolling.** If the question is, say, on gender issues or women's rights, I downvote answers based on personal opinions. Example: "Women should know their place" answer on this example gets downvote for me.

**2: Your answer is too simplified or too hand-wavy** Again, if I ask about, say, generational ships and how to survive 600 years, I tend to downvote answers saying "Just put them into a freezer."

**3: You answer something I did not ask about** Example, if I ask about using poison, I do not like getting answers that say I should use a bomb in that scenario.

**4: I am not really sure what you are saying:** Although I am a non-English speaker myself, I can understand *some* typos. But if I cannot understand, I downvote. However, I usually comment when this is the case.

### They are just internet points

I know it is easy to say when I myself have 12,196 of them and you have just six. But remember, it's just virtual points, nothing more. Whenever you get downvoted, take deep breath and try remind yourself of this.

### Post specific examples here

The point that you have just six internet points can have an effect on people downvoting you. I have been in several online communities, so I can safely assume that someone looking down on new users can happen here, as it was common in several communities I have been part of.

**This is what the Meta is here for**: Post links to specific question or answers which got downvoted. It will get more attention from moderators and/or experienced users.

My personal experiences with the Worldbuilding community is that it is a welcoming community full of people willing to help you provide better questions or answers and get more internet points.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't not exactly the best practice to downvote something just because you can't understand it? I mean, if it is completely incomprehensible, I understand, but if you can get through the question and understand the gist of the question, it's unfair to simply downvote the question or answer because the poster may not be a native English speaker. The better alternative would be to gently correct the OP/answer and point the user in the direction of ELL.

Comment: I edited your post a little to improve your grammar and some spelling.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Thank you. I make too much typos when trying to get the thoughts out *fast*

Comment: @PavelJanicek Don't worry about it, you're not a native English speaker, and I'm a grammar fanatic.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon being Czech grammar fanatic, I know the struggle :)

Answer (score 6):

I only see one question on your account. In the case of that question they most likely also started a close vote, with the close vote reason being the same as for the downvote: Your question is not actually about worldbuilding.

If you read the tour and in particular the sections about what to ask and what not to ask that should help you consider how to re-ask the question in a way that will be better received.

Comment: That's why I clearly mentioned I hold accounts in 21 sites of stack exchange. My question was out of the experience I had with 21 sites of stack exchange.

Comment: @GaneshRamachandran I don't want to appear to diminish you, but Stack Exchange has a way to reflect that experience. Once you get to 200 reputation point in one site, they automatically give you 100 on each other site, so that you can get passt the lower rights (upvote, flag, chat, comments, etc.). You did not yet get to that. And I agree with Tim, your question is off-topic on our site: it is not about worldbuilding. We have a sandbox here on meta where you can ask questions and get a feedback.

Comment: And to add a positive note, many of our highest ranked users (by reputation) have had questions closed, and questions downvoted. Possibly both at once. Yet it did not prevent them to get where they are now.